# Avoiding Under-/ Overflow with double on "simple Summation"

Tags: c++, double, overflow

I am struggeling with a summation problem which fails with under or overflow.

I have over 8271571 double values from which I need the arithmetical mean.

But the main problem is, that I don't seem to be smart enough to do this.

Currently I am just sum them up and divide by the size. 
This fails for most of the time in an under or overflow, giving me -1.#INF or 1.#INF.

```
for(size_t j = 0; j < 12; j++)
{
    double a = 0.0;

    for(size_t i=0; i < Features->size(); i++)
    {
        a += Features->at(i)->at(j);
    }
    meanVector[j] = a / Features->size();
}
```

There is however no possibilty to say its just positive or negative value, so I can not set the data type to be signed.

I also tried to use a division-constant in the summation or dividing by the size already when I add them up, but that doesn't help either.

Values may range, from what I have seen on a quick look, from -20 to +30, but can't say that for sure.

So maybe anyone can give me a hint on how to do the math or use a workaround. This must be able but I just lack ideas.

Edit:

The size is never 0, a checkup is done in front of the division.
Further on  none of the values is invalid in any way. While extracting them I already do a check for #IND and NaN.

If I divide already on the summation, I guess this is also no correct result?

```
a+= Features->at(i)->at(j) / Features->size()
```

results in -3.7964983860343639e+305

but for every iteration. This can't be right and looks like a boundary

Edit 2:

So some of you guys were totally right. There is lots of garbage sh*t going on..

> 0: size: 8327571, min: -2.24712e+307, max: 3362.12 1: size: 8327571,
>   min: -2.24712e+307, max: 142181 2: size: 8327571, min: -2.24712e+307,
>   max: 59537.8 3: size: 8327571, min: -2.24712e+307, max: 236815 4:
>   size: 8327571, min: -2.24712e+307, max: 353488 5: size: 8327571, min:
>   -2.24712e+307, max: 139960 6: size: 8327571, min: 0, max: 0 7: size: 8327571, min: 0, max: 0 8: size: 8327571, min: 0, max: 0 9: size:
>   8327571, min: 0, max: 0 10: size: 8327571, min: 0, max: 0 11: size:
>   8327571, min: 0, max: 0

Comment: You can sum `number[i]/n` - but it might increase the numeric error...

Comment: Are you sure, if all `Features->size()` are not `0`? (hint: any floating point number, divided by 0 will give you infinity - if the number is non-negative - `1.#INF`, if it's negative - `-1.#INF`)

Comment: It's also possible that one of the values being summed is +/-INF - you should add an assert to check for this.

Comment: I edited some information for what you asked.

Comment: It seems unlikely that even `max of size_t` values ranging from -20 to 30 could possibly reach the end of `double`'s range.  I think one of your assumptions is incorrect.

Comment: **Post a complete minimal example that exhibits the problem.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> - I have over 8271571 double values from which I need the arithmetical mean.
> - Values may range, from what I have seen on a quick look, from -20 to
>     +30, but can't say that for sure.
> - The size is never 0, a checkup is done in front of the division.

This doesn't add up. The sum should fit in `double` easily. There must be something wrong with the data. You can make a quick inspection of your values like this:

```
for (size_t j = 0; j < 12; ++j)
{
    std::vector<double> values;

    values.reserve(Features->size());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < Features->size(); ++i)
    {
        values.push_back(Features->at(i)->at(j));
    }

    // Find extreme values, including infinity
    std::cout << j << ": " 
              << "size: " << values.size() 
              << ", min: " << *std::min_element(values.begin(), values.end())
              << ", max: " << *std::max_element(values.begin(), values.end())
              << std::endl;

    // Find NaNs
    for (size_t i = 0; i < Features->size(); ++i)
    {
        // Choose one of the following ifs

        // For C++11 (isnan is a standard thing now)
        if (std::isnan(Features->at(i)->at(j))

        // Or for Visual Studio
        if (_isnan(Features->at(i)->at(j))

        // Or for GCC prior to C++11
        if (__builtin_isnan(Features->at(i)->at(j))

        {
            std::cout << "NaN at [" << i << ", " << j << "]" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

You should be able to quickly spot if there's anything odd with the input.

Comment: +1. *This doesn't add up* - both literally and figuratively. There's something funky with some of the data. I suspect some of the values haven't been initialized. These numbers presumably represent something physical. Whether it's meters, kilograms, #people, whatever, 10^300 of them is a garbage value.

Comment: +1 you both are totally right!
0: size: 8327571, min: -2.24712e+307, max: 3362.12
1: size: 8327571, min: -2.24712e+307, max: 142181
2: size: 8327571, min: -2.24712e+307, max: 59537.8
3: size: 8327571, min: -2.24712e+307, max: 236815
4: size: 8327571, min: -2.24712e+307, max: 353488
5: size: 8327571, min: -2.24712e+307, max: 139960
6: size: 8327571, min: 0, max: 0
7: size: 8327571, min: 0, max: 0
8: size: 8327571, min: 0, max: 0
9: size: 8327571, min: 0, max: 0
10: size: 8327571, min: 0, max: 0
11: size: 8327571, min: 0, max: 0
What a bunch of garbage sh*t and shame on me!

Comment: Hi, I have now "solved" getting garbage data. There was a little bug when reading the data.. Anyhow I found a strange behaviour. Checking the elements with your loops works fine and gives me nice and smooth data. No errors or garbage values. But if I sum them up later, I find a value that is in the vector -1.#IND .. but while pushing it in the loop to values it is not. Accessing it directly with the known index I can see again #IND.. crazy ?

Comment: @Stefan, you have NaNs in your data. It cannot be detected by `min/max_element`. I edited the code to specifically look for those. If you don't know what NaN is you can read about it here (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN). Basically it's not-a-number, like the result of `sqrt(-1)`.

Comment: Yeah, I know what NaNs are and made a checkup with value != value to detect them. But I didn't know that min/max couldn't detect them. Thank you to come back and making it more clearer :-)

Comment: @Stefan, `value != value` doesn't always work. I compilers think then can optimized that. `isnan` is your friend. `min_element` cannot detected them because they are neither `<` nor `>` than any other element. In some specially crafted situations you can have it returned by `min_element`, but not in general case.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the mean using an online algorithm, which means you don't have to add all values before dividing. Here:

```
template< typename NumberType >
class ProgressiveMean{
    NumberType  m_Mean;
    NumberType  m_MeanKMinus1;
    long        m_K;
public:
    ProgressiveMean();
    void Seed( NumberType seed );
    void AddValue( NumberType newVal );
    NumberType getMean() const;
};

template< typename NumberType >
ProgressiveMean<NumberType>::ProgressiveMean():
    m_Mean( 0 ),
    m_MeanKMinus1( 0 ),
    m_K( 0 ){
}

template< typename NumberType >
void ProgressiveMean<NumberType>::Seed( NumberType seed ){
    m_MeanKMinus1 = seed
    m_K = 2;  //Start from K = 1, so next one is 2
}

template< typename NumberType >
void ProgressiveMean<NumberType>::AddValue( NumberType newVal ){
    m_Mean = m_MeanKMinus1 + (newVal - m_MeanKMinus1) / m_K;
    m_MeanKMinus1 = m_Mean;
    m_K++;
}

template< typename NumberType >
NumberType ProgressiveMean<NumberType>::getMean() const{
    return m_Mean;
}
```

To use this, call `Seed` with the initial value, loop calling `AddValue` for the rest, and when you're done, call `getMean`.

This idea is from Knuth, and I got it from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Online_algorithm).

You can also consider using a big number library.